# Why Ionic generate QR code instead of Barcode?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, barcode-scanner

Did the following:-

```
encodeText() {
 this.barcode.encode(this.barcode.Encode.TEXT_TYPE,this.barcodeData).then((encodedData) => {
  this.encodedData = encodedData;

  }, (err) => {
  console.log("Error occured : " + err);
});
```

}

Why It will generate QR code on screen, I want to generate barcode how I can achieve this in ionic?

Comment: what is the plugin name that you are using?

Comment: @ionic-native/barcode-scanner

Comment: Please check my answer @Rajat.r2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, according to [this](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/issues/96#issuecomment-314564902), @ionic-native/barcode-scanner does not support Barcode encoding as of now.

> I would suggest to use node package, like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-barcode)

Though its not made for ionic, you can still use `require()` and import the module

Comment: Thanks It works, But also I am having ionic native barcode scanner in my project when I install ngx library it will remove ionic native scanner.